# AndroidでHorizontalScrollViewを継承したCustomViewが横スクロールしない

Tags: android, java

お世話になります。
表題の通り、HorizontalScrollviewを継承したCustomViewを作成し、
xmlにCustomViewを配置したのですが、何故か横スクロールされずに困っております。

CustomView

```
public final class ScrollCustom extends HorizontalScrollView {


    public ScrollCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public ScrollCustom(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
        super(context, att);
    }
    public ScrollCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxScrollAmount() {
        return super.getMaxScrollAmount();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
        Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onInterceptTouchEvent");

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.downWidth = x;
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.downHeight = y;

                screenX = x;
                screenY = y;
                Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_DOWN " + x + " : " + y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.moveWidth = x;
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.moveHeight = y;
                Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_MOVE " + x + " : " + y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.upWidth = x;
                TaskRecyclerAdapter.upHeight = y;
                Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_UP " + x + " : " + y);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
        Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onTouchEvent");
        return false;
    }
}
```

xml

```
 <number_8.co.jp.constructiontaskapp.view.ScrollCustom
    android:id="@+id/kanban_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/kanban_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</number_8.co.jp.constructiontaskapp.view.ScrollCustom>
```

初心者ですのでおかしな点はあると思いますが
ご教示の程よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HorizontalScrollviewではonInterceptTouchEvent/onTouchEventで様々な処理を行っています。
スクロール処理が動作しないのはonInterceptTouchEvent/onTouchEventをOverrideしているからではないでしょうか。

挙動を書き換えることが目的でないのであれば、それぞれのreturnを以下のように書き換えてあげるとスクロール処理が動作するのではないでしょうか。

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
    Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onInterceptTouchEvent");
(中略)
//    returnを書き換える
//    return false;
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
    Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onTouchEvent");
//    returnを書き換える
//    return false;
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
早速書き換えて見ましたが動きませんでした...
お忙しい中ありがとうございました。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。
ご指摘いただいたコードを追記することで動きました！
僕の勘違いでした。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決されたようで何よりです。私の回答だけで解決されたのでしょうか？litmonさんの回答と合わせて解決されたのであれば、ご自身で改めて完全な解決方法を回答として記載されると、今後似たような問題を解決される方の助けになります。また、解決した回答を承認ください。

Comment: maot様回答で解決致しました。
お世話になりました。

Answer (score 0):

`CustomView`の中の`RecyclerView`が `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` で設定されていたりしませんか？
xmlの定義を見た限りでは、`RecyclerView`の横幅が`CustomView`の横幅と同じに設定されている(`match_parent`)ため、そもそもスクロールもしない気がしますが、縦にスクロールされているのは`RecyclerView`の中にある要素が縦にスクロールされているのではないかと思いました。

`RecyclerView`に設定している`LinearLayoutManager`を以下のように設定してみてはどうでしょう？

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
無事、動かすことができました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

maot様回答より

```
@Override
　public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
@Override
　public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

上記メソッドの返り値を以下に変更で動きました。

```
  return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

解決したコード

```
public final class ScrollCustom extends HorizontalScrollView {


  public ScrollCustom(Context context) {
     super(context);
  }
  public ScrollCustom(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
    super(context, att);
  }
  public ScrollCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
   public int getMaxScrollAmount() {
     return super.getMaxScrollAmount();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
    Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onInterceptTouchEvent");

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.downWidth = x;
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.downHeight = y;

            screenX = x;
            screenY = y;
            Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_DOWN " + x + " : " + y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.moveWidth = x;
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.moveHeight = y;
            Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_MOVE " + x + " : " + y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.upWidth = x;
            TaskRecyclerAdapter.upHeight = y;
            Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + ", ACTION_UP " + x + " : " + y);
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
 }

  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
     Log.v("Test", "RecycleTest" + " onTouchEvent");
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

}